# IntelliJ Cursive s-form documentation on hover over

Tags: eclipse, clojure, cursive, intellij-idea-2016

Is it possible to have IntelliJ/Cursive display a pop-up with s-form's definition and documentation when that s-form is hovered over with a mouse, like it's done in Eclipse? Ctrl+Q seems to bring up the window, but I'd like for it to open up automatically without me hitting a shortcut.  Is this a configurable setting or something? Also, what is a similar key combination to bring up a source pop-up?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this automatically on hover. You can see the source pop-up using *View->Quick Definition* - the keybinding will depend on the keymap and platform you're using. The keybinding should be shown in the menu, otherwise you can search for "Quick Definition" in *Settings->Keymap*.